# Adding event handler before initializier is called

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, initializer

I have my two classes `MainWindow` and `Foo` and have a slight problem considering timing:

```
class MainWindow : Window
{
    internal void SomeMethod(string name)
    {
        Foo foo = new foo(name)
        foo.MyEventHandler += EventHandlerMethod;
    }

    internal void EventHandlerMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something after foo is done initializing stuff
    }
}

class Foo
{
    internal event EventHandler MyEventHandler;

    internal Foo(string name)
    {
        //start another thread that will at some point via event call FooMethod()
    }

    private void FooMethod()
    {
        MyEventHandler(this, null);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot guarantee how long the `Foo`-initialized thread will take and `FooMethod();` might be called before `MyEventHandler` has been added.

I thought of a possible solution to simply not add the initializer but have a separate method and simply call that one after adding the event, but in general, is there a way to add events BEFORE the initializer is called?

Comment: Sure, just add a Foo.StartWork() method.  Easy peasy.  Ensuring that thread will stop raising events after the window is closed is the problem you really should be worrying about.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I already mentioned that in my last sentence. My question was actually about something else. And yes, I have already made sure that no events are raised if the window has been closed.

Comment: I need information from Foo in the MainWindow after the initialization is complete. And I use threads because the initialization can take up to one minute and I don't want the UI to freeze

Comment: How about using TPL, [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) ?

Comment: Everything is working just fine by using threads, but my question is simply about something else, sorry if I sound rude, I really don't mean to.

Comment: Maybe a static MyEventHandler if it doesn't cause new problems. Or you pass MyEventHandler in constructor too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't do before, but you can doing it as part of the constructor. Just pass the handler in as a parameter.

However, that's pretty ugly.   Having constructors that spawn threads is not nice, much better having a "Start" method

Comment: THank you for your answer. The reason why I went with the constructor was simple in the beginning: The thread has to be called, as I need to open and initialize a lot of data from a file and `Foo` will contain all the data, hence, no long init in a different thread, no foo. The problem appeared when I now realized that in some rare cases I need a signal to `MainWindow` when the thread is done.